# Columns.Bound cannot resolve symbol 'Bound'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a web page that has some Kendo controls like dropdown and button working successfully, but adding a *Grid* is causing a problem.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("grid").Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(stuff => stuff.FirstColumn).Width(200);
      columns.Bound(stuff => stuff.SecondColumn).Width(200);
      columns.Bound(stuff => stuff.HiddenColumn).Hidden;
      columns.Bound(stuff => stuff.ThirdVisibleColumn).Width(200);
  })
  .Pagable()
  .Sortable()
  )
```

At design time, the .Bound method is showing in red font with the tooltip *Cannot resolve the symbol 'Bound'*, and the properties of *Stuff* (e.g. .FirstColumn) are also in red with similar messages.

***Compilation Error***

*Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.*

*Compiler Error Message: CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type*

This problem first showed up in another project, so as a test I created a new Telerik prject and added just the minimum required to reproduce the problem in the hope that a newly created project would highlight where the original one had failed.  No such luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the model like this it needs to be of type IEnumerable (or similar).

This works for me:

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeModel>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(stuff => stuff.FirstColumn).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(stuff => stuff.SecondColumn).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(stuff => stuff.HiddenColumn).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(stuff => stuff.ThirdVisibleColumn).Width(200);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
)
```

Comment: Thanks Nic.  The HomeControler.cs provides:
`        public ActionResult About()

        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            var lotsOfStuff = new List<Stuff>();
            var stuff1 = new Stuff();
            var stuff2 = new Stuff();
            var stuff3 = new Stuff();
            lotsOfStuff.Add(stuff1);
            lotsOfStuff.Add(stuff2);
            lotsOfStuff.Add(stuff3);

            return View(lotsOfStuff);
        }


Note the output is List<Stuff>

Comment: What does the view look like? For design-time the controller doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, Nic.  I missed your point about providing a structure for the View at design time.  Although I don't understand why it would still not run if the View is being passed in at run time.

Adding @model IEnumerable<Stuff> beforehand worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can pass model like:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeModel>().Name("grid")
              .DataSource(src => src.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("Action", "Controller"))
              .Columns(col =>
              {
                  col.Bound(e => e.Name);
                  col.Bound(e => e.Age);
                  col.Bound(e => e.ID);
              })
              .Selectable()
              .Scrollable()
        )
```